# Can I upload Django project on Cpanel without CloudLinux installed

Tags: python, django

Hey guys i have made my django project successfully and I was ready to upload my django project to cpanel Linux shared Hosting which I bought but when I searched on Google on how to upload Django project to cpanel I found that there is a option in cpanel called Setup Python App which gives us features to upload Python Apps and this option is only shown on cpanels which have CloudLinux but I don't have CloudLinux and it is paid. My cpanel is only showing me Application Manager kind of thing under Software Option which I think could be an alternative to upload my app. Am I right, can I really do that with Application manager thing or is there any free way to upload my Django App on my bought cpanel. I bought Linux shared hosting in cpanel and bought a domain too. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

if you do have application manager  on your cpanel  there might be a way to run python WSGI application ( in your case the python WSGI will be your django app )
look at this article (https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/installing-python-wsgi-applications-on-cpanel/)
flowing the steps of this article  you  should be able to bring your  django application on cpanel without the need buy CloudLinux which is TOOOOOO expensive  for the only one little tiny thing you want from it

please not  that   since  your cpanel allready have  [Application manager] then you can skip the "yum install ea-ruby24-mod_passenger ea-apache24-mod_env"   step   as it  would only be required if  you don't already see Application manager on your cpanel account

to summerize the steps  for you

1 :   from your terminal (ssh) log in to your  user account , and get into your  user main directory ( or wherever you want to have your django appstored)
cd /home/username

2: create a virtual environment identical to your virtualenv on your local machine

3: put your django project file on your server ( you need to figure this out on your own )
4: create the Passenger WSGI file ( ideally  on the same directory where  you have your manage.py file

> note that  your  django application  should  have its own wsgi.py   file  right next to settings.py

so   instead of writing the Passenger WSGI file as described  in the link ,

you would need  to   put only one line of code in it to import   the django wsgi file

> from project_name.wsgi import application

Comment: from my terminal login, i am facing a message that 'username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.' and can not login